# USB-C charge only?

Tags: usb, usb-c

I have a USB-A <-> USB-C cable that appears to be charge only, that is I can't get it a PC to recognize the Android device. So either:

1. USB-C cables do come charge only
2. The cable is defective.

Is 1 a possibility?

Also the cable does have the 'pitchfork' on it, plus SS (for SuperSpeed) and on the other side, 'IIIP' which I would guess is the manufacturer.

Edit:
Egregious error, one end is USB-A not B.

Comment: Never seen one that is charge only. Try a different cable. What OS are you trying to connect to?

Comment: If it has the USB logo on it, it can't (legally) be charge only.  Anything with the logo is supposed to comply with the USB specs, and the specs don't allow a charge-only cable.  Anyone can make a charge-only cable, but it isn't supposed to carry the logo.

Comment: PortaPow makes a charge-only USB-C cable, so they exist.

Comment: How did you manage to plug B-cable into PC? PC Hosts have Type-A receptacles, and need Type-A end of cable, not "USB-B".

Comment: @Moab16: Windows 10 <> Android

Comment: @AliChen; You are correct. I made a mistake in the original question, which I have corrected.

Comment: @fixer1234: Thanks I did not know this with respect to the spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USB-type-B means that this end of cable should go to **USB DEVICE**. Therefore the USB-B to USB-C cable is meant to turn the Type-C gadget into host, aka "OTG",  which turns your Android into USB Host mode. If you try some gender-changer on USB-B side to accommodate the USB-A receptacle in PC, you will be connecting host-to-host, and VBUS power will be in conflict and even fry something. At least there will be no USB communication for sure. But of course there is a possibility that the cable is el-cheapo "for charging only".

To make your Type-C phone to appear as USB device to a PC, you need USB-A to USB-C cable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A very bad error in the original question. Please see edit.

Comment: And, I should add, that based on your answer and the comments above, I think the cable is defective.